# Bootstrap - image responding when screen size decreases

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-resizing

I'm using the most recent version of bootstrap. I'm having trouble when resizing my page and keeping an image at the correct aspect ratio. This is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 boximage">
        <img class="img-responsive" title="" src="themes/regulartopheavy/img/gardening.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 boxholder">
        <div class="homeinfobox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
    .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-3.col-xs-12.boximage {
        padding-left: 15px;
        display: block;
        height: 234px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-3.col-xs-12.boximage > img {
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

I want my image size to be the same height as the 'boxholder' which contains text and doesn't have a set height because when the page resizes the text becomes longer, and the same width of the `col-lg-4`.

Since I have a set height of `234px` it's fine when it's full screen but when the text grows as the browser windows is decreased, the image doesn't resize to be the height of the div.

How can set the height of the div to always be the same of the 'boxholder' div and have the image maintain the same aspect ratio (not bothered if it overflows outside of the div and crops the image)?

Comment: Start by removing class="img-responsive" from img tag in HTML. There is no use for it, because img-responsive is for image width, but you need image height to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a good/simple solution for this problem, but i had this issue myself a while back, and i used javascript to get around that problem.
Below is a fiddle and code i used. ( you can click the button to size up the text, or drag the window smaller/bigger)

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/gokfw2kg/8/)

Html

```
<div class="col-1">
I want my image size to be the same height as the 'boxholder' which contains text and doesn't have a set height because when the page resizes the text becomes longer, and the same width of the col-lg-4.

Since i have a set height of 234px its fine when it's full screen but when the text grows as the browser windows is decreased, the image doesn't resize to be the height of the div.
</div>

<div class="col-2">
    <img src="http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/kynkw3shz8y768tm7tbw.jpg" alt="some image"/> 
</div>
<div style="clear: both; height: 10px">___</div>

<br/>
<input type="button" value="size up"/>
```

CSS

```
img {margin: 0;width: 100%;}
.col-1, .col-2 {width: 45%;float: left;background: #FDFDFD;margin: 1px; border: 1px solid gray;}
```

JavaScript

```
var scaleToFit=function(t,i){var h,e,o,d,n,s=!1,a=t.width,g=t.height,r={};return i.padding&&(s=parseInt(i.padding),i.width-=2*s,i.height-=2*s),e=i.width,o=i.height,h=a/g,d=Math.abs(e-a),n=Math.abs(o-g),r.x=i.x,r.y=i.y,a>e||g>o?a-e>g-o?(r.width=e,r.height=g*(1-d/a)):(r.height=o,r.width=a*(o/g)):d>n?(r.width=a*(1+n/g),r.height=o):(r.height=g*(1+d/a),r.width=e),i.width>r.width&&(r.x=i.x+Math.round((i.width-r.width)/2)),i.height>r.height&&(r.y=i.y+Math.round((i.height-r.height)/2)),s&&(r.x+=s,r.y+=s),r};!function(t){t.fn.scaleToFit=function(){return t.each(this,function(i,h){var e,o,d,n,s=t(h),a=s.parent(),g={},r={};o=a.css("position"),a.css("position","relative"),e=s.position(),d=s.outerWidth(),n=s.outerHeight(),g={x:e.left,y:e.top,width:d,height:n},d=a.outerWidth(),n=a.outerHeight(),r={x:0,y:0,width:d,height:n},g=scaleToFit(g,r),s.css({position:"relative",top:g.y,left:g.x,width:g.width,height:g.height}),a.css("position",o)}),this}}(jQuery);

var sizeChange = function() {
    var newHeight = $(".col-1").height();
    $(".col-2").height(newHeight + "px");
    $("img").scaleToFit();    
}

var scaleUp = function () {
    var font = parseInt($(".col-1").css("font-size"));
    $(".col-1").css("font-size", (font + 1) + "px");
    sizeChange();

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    sizeChange();
    $("img").scaleToFit();
    window.onresize = function() {
        sizeChange();
    }
    $("input").click(function() {
       scaleUp();
    });
});
```